# Django Tutorial Error in Tutorial 4 (OperationalError at /polls/1/)

Tags: python, django

I m new to coding and web development, but I am keen to learn and progress.

I have encountered this error during template rendering. Checked issues but cant find any answer can anyone help on this. Not able to understand what is the operational error.

Error displayed on screen is as follows

```
OperationalError at /polls/1/
no such column: polls_choice.id
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/
Django Version: 3.2.1
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such column: polls_choice.id
Exception Location: /Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mysite_dj1/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py, line 423, in execute
Python Executable:  /Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mysite_dj1/venv/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.9.0
Python Path:    
['/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mysite_dj1/mysite',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mysite_dj1/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 07 May 2021 10:20:59 +0530
Error during template rendering
In template /Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mysite_dj1/mysite/polls/templates/polls/detail.html, error at line 10

no such column: polls_choice.id
1   
2   <!--Option 3-->
3   
4   <h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
5   
6   {% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
7   
8   <form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question_id=question.id %}" method="post">
9   {% csrf_token %}
10  {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
11      <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
12      <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
13  {% endfor %}
14  <input type="submit" value="Vote">
15  </form>
16  
17  <!--
18  {{ question }}
19  
20  -->
```

**polls/views.py**

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a Choice",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', kwargs={'pk': question.id}))
```

polls/templates/polls/detail.html

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question_id=question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

poll/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from polls import views

app_name = 'polls'

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    path("<int:question_id>/", views.detail, name="detail"),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    path("<int:question_id>/results/", views.results, name="results"),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    path("<int:question_id>/vote/", views.vote, name="vote"),
]
```

poll/models.py

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class Question(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=208)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
    
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=208)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  From my quick glance,  your ```Choice``` model doesn't have an ```id``` column.

Comment: If you check the migrations 0001_initial.py it has ID column.. code is as follows `migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Choice',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('choice_text', models.CharField(max_length=208)),
                ('votes', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
                ('question', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='polls.question')),
            ],
        ),
    ]`